# Can I use custom @font-face font with same name as built-in font?

Tags: css, font-face

If I have a custom font and I call it 'verdana', will that conflict with the browser's built-in verdana font? When I do:

```
font-family: 'verdana';
```

will the browser use my custom font or the built-in one?

Comment: Fonts are not "built-in" to the browser.  They are rendered by the OS.  You would have to replace the user's Verdana font in the OS, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom font name that may coincide with the name of an installed font. It might be confusing, though, and might look suspicious (using a font illegally) to use a name like Verdana, if someone peeks at your code.

The CSS3 Fonts draft [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-desc): “If the font family name [in `@font-face`] is the same as a font family available in a given user's environment, it effectively hides the underlying font for documents that use the stylesheet. This permits a web author to freely choose font-family names without worrying about conflicts with font family names present in a given user's environment.”

Comment: Safari breaks this rule with 'Helvetica' (a bug I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You may find parts of this article interesting: http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3080-How-Browsers-Manage-Fonts.

The short answer is that the browser should use whatever version of Verdana you have installed. The exception here is if you are using "src: url()", then it should load the font file from that URL. A good resource if that is the case: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/.

If you're wanting to use your font and you worry that some browsers may just up and decide to use the local Verdana, you can rename the ttf or eot on your server and just use Verdana-Mine as the font-family and src as url('verdana-mine.ttf').